# How to convert a number to a specific format in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to show a number 1000000 in the format 10,00,000 in PHP.

What is the PHP function to do this conversion?

Comment: `number_format` should not be that difficult to find.

Comment: a 3 sec search on google wil give you the solution : number_format

Comment: @Jon, Actually i am unable to remember this format name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to display a value formatted as Lakhs and Crores:

```
$amount = 1000000000;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
$amount = money_format('%!i', $amount);
echo $amount;
```

should give `100,00,00,000` instead of `1,000,000,000`

Comment: What does LC_MONETARY means?

Comment: It means use locale-specific monetary formatting (currency, groupings, etc) with the money_format() function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 5):

use number_format function

```
<?php

echo number_format(100000); // prints 1,000,000

?>
```